# What type of Class Decorator to use for a non-GUI Class in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I want to take advantage of Object Oriented principles and group my code into classes.  However, my classes frequently have dependencies on either @angular libraries or services that I have created.

Using the `new` operator is out because many libraries fail without the DI framework.

What is the proper way to make a plain old class that depends on @angular libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is safe to say that if I plan on a class depending on @angular dependencies, I should just use `@Injectable()` and create it as a service?

Comment: Yes. That's the meaning behind `@Injectable` decorator.